# error de desplazamiento

Tags: php, html, mysql

estoy trabajando en un carrito y al mostrar todos los productos en una tabla me marca un error "Intentando acceder al desplazamiento de matriz en el valor de tipo bool " , ya verifique todo mi codigo
porfavor necesito su ayuda llevo trabando varios dia en esto y es un proyecto para la escuela y al parecer esta bien, estoy trabajando con php el error me lo marca en el forech de lista carrito y producto mi codigo es el siguiente
no se a que se deba el error ya le pregunte a mis profesores y no me dan una respuesta, me estoy guiando con un video pero ya compare codigos y estan iguales

```
require 'config.php';
require 'database.php';
$db= new Database(); //instanciamos a la clase de la carpeta condig/database
$con=$db->conectar();
$productos=isset($_SESSION['carrito']['productos']) ? $_SESSION['carrito']['productos'] : null;
$lista_carrito= array();
print_r($_SESSION);
if($productos != null){
    foreach($productos as $clave => $cantidad){
        $sql=$con->prepare("SELECT id, nombre, descripcion, precio, descuento, $cantidad AS cantidad FROM productos WHERE id=? AND activo=1");
        $sql->execute([$clave]); 
        $lista_carrito[]=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}

/*$sql-- con esto creamos consultas preparadas*/
/*$sql->execute()  con esto la variable se ejecuta, una vez que se ejecuta se trae al resultado*/
/* $resulado--estamos llamando a todos los productos que esten en la tabla, idicamos que los traiga mediante PDO::FETCH_ASSOC-->asocia mediante el nombre de cada columna*/
//session_destroy();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>tienda online</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">

</head>

<body>
    <header>

       
        <div class="navbar navbar-espand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark ">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                    <strong>Tienda</strong>
                
                <div style="display:inline-block">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0" style="display:inline-block">

                    <a href="checar.php" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Carrito<span id="num_cart" class="badge bg-secondary"><?php echo $num_cart;?></span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="vistaVnededor.php" class="btn btn-primary">
                         vendedor
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!--contenido-->
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Producto</th>
                            <th>Precio</th>
                            <th>cantidad</th>
                            <th>subtotal</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php if($lista_carrito == null) {
                            echo '<tr><td  colspan="5" class="text-center"><b>lista vacia</b></td></tr>';

                        }else{
                            $total=0;
                            foreach($lista_carrito as $producto){
                                $_id = $producto['id'];
                                $nombre = $producto['nombre'];
                                $precio = $producto['precio'];
                                $descuento = $producto['descuento'];
                                $cantidad = $producto['cantidad'];
                                $precio_desc = $precio -(($precio* $descuento)/100);
                                $subtotal = $cantidad*$precio_desc;
                                $total+=$subtotal;
                                ?>
                            
                        
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $nombre; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo  MONEDA . number_format($precio_desc,2,'.',','); ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="number" min="1" max="10" step="1" value="<?php echo $cantidad?>" size="5" id="cantidad_<?php echo $_id;?>" onchange="">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="" id="subtotal_<?php echo $_id;?>" name="subtotal[]"><?php echo  MONEDA . number_format($subtotal, 2, '.', ',');?></div>
                            </td>
                            <td><a href="#" id="eliminar" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-bs-id="<?php echo $_id;?>" data-bs-toogle="modal" data-bs-target="eliminaModal">Eliminar</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                    <?php } ?>
                </table>
            </div>
           
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            function addProducto(id,token){
            //api fech que proporcina javaScript
            let url='carrito.php'
            let formData = new FormData() //ayuda a mandar los parametros por metodo post
            formData.append('id',id)
            formData.append('token',token)
            fetch(url,{
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
                mode: 'cors'
            }).then(response=> response.json())
            .then(data=> {
                if(data.ok){
                    let elemento= document.getElementById("num_cart")
                    elemento.innerHTML=data.numero
                }
            })

            }
            </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Saludos. Prueba cambiando **$lista_carrito[]=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);** a **$lista_carrito=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);**

Comment: Hola. ¿Puedes explicar qué es lo que intentas hacer con este código? No es una buena idea lanzar consultas dentro de un bucle. Si hay 1000 artículos, 1000 consultas, si hay 1 millón de artículos, 1 millón de consultas. Las consultas tienen un coste. Debería considerar en optimizar, usando por ejemplo `WHERE IN(AQUI-LISTA-DE-IDS)`